# Bootstrap.: col-sm behave much early. i,e when the size less than 767px it became col-sm

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating responive site. I know the col-sm starts when the screen size is smaller than 576px. But in my code, it behave much early.  I am not good at English. hope I can make mylself clear.  What I want to display when the screen size is between 767px and 500px is like so(image below):  But in my code(I attached the link below) it does not behave like that. How can I do that? thanks in advance

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

For less than 500px screens I want to display it like so :[Code pen Link][2]

```
<div class="col-12">
    <h3>Oda Seçenekleri</h3>
    <div class="room-outer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-12" id="res_img">
          <div class="room-left">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img src="./img/room-1.jpg" class="image">
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h6>  Manzaralı</h6>
                <ul>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-bed"></i>Çift yatak</li>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i>3 </li>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-bed"></i>80 ㎡</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#">Detaylı  Bilgisi <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-12" id="res_img_two">
          <div class="room-right">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-12">
                <ul>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-bed" style="border:1px solid #fff6d6; padding:5px 3px; border-radius: 4px;"></i> tek geniş yatak</li>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i><span Çocuk Ücretsiz</span></li>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-bed"></i><span> İptal</span></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
                <div class="room-price">
                  <p> 3 Gece için Toplam:</p>
                  <span>1.900 TL</span>
                  <a href="#">ODAYI SEÇ</a>
                </div>                   
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I would first begin with restructuring your HTML. Bootstrap works by having a Container in which you can insert a Row and then inside the Row you can insert Columns. You seem to have Rows inside Columns inside Rows inside Columns.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob hey thanks for reply. isnt it ok to use like I do? I do not see any problems having rows inside columns.

Comment: It will physically work in some manner to do it the way you have but it isn't really how Bootstrap was designed and it is sure to mess about with your over all layout. Begin with a Container, put your Row inside that and then add up to 12 columns per Row. Then you can start a new Row beneath that and add more columns.

Comment: Got to correct myself.... You can have more than 12 Columns per Row but a maximum of 12 Columns can appear next to each other one one line before they wrap around underneath each other.